# How to remove a specific character in a string?

Tags: sql-server

i have a value of 1;16;23;117 in a specific column and i wanted to trim 16 and have a result of 1;23;117. Number may vary. It is possible that i may also commit a different number. How can i do that in sql server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = replace(FieldName, 'old', 'new')
```

Answer (score 0):

msdn says:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

So you can use:

```
REPLACE ( colname , '16;' , '' )
```